# Converting 1 to HDD in zabbix item -> preprocessing

Tags: zabbix

**Item key is:**

> system.run[cat /sys/block/sda/queue/rotational]

[image: image of item key configuration]

**Item preprocessing is**

`^.*1.*$ -> HDD`

[image: image of preprocessing configuration]

**Dashboard shows 1 and not HDD**

[image: Image of the dashboard]

Why?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation: `Failure to match the input value will make the item unsupported`.

I've implemented your setup and in fact:

`item "MyZabbix:system.run[cat /sys/block/sda/queue/rotational]" became not supported: Item preprocessing step #2 failed: cannot perform regular expression match on value "HDD" of type "string": pattern does not match`

This means that the first regexp runs correctly, but of course the second does not match.

You need to implement a [Value Map](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/config/items/mapping):

- build a Value Map with `0->SSD`, `1-HDD` and call it `"Disk Type"`
- remove the preprocessing from the item
- reconfigure the item as `"Numeric (Unsigned)"`
- reconfigure the item `Show Value` parameter from `"As is"` to `"Disk Type"`